# nunit testing of method which calls other method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Am very new to nunit.below is the business unit code

```
public enum HighlightType
{
    IP,
    Item,
    Address
}

public class UniformGridHighlighting
{
    public static event HighlightingChangedDelegate HighlightingChanged;

    private static List<string> _highlightedIPs = new List<string>();
    private static List<long> _highlightedItems = new List<long>();
    private static ContactInfoType _highlightedAddress;

    public static void ClearIPHighlighting()
    {
        _highlightedIPs.Clear();
        OnHighlightingChanged(HighlightType.IP);
    }

    private static void OnHighlightingChanged(HighlightType type)
    {
        if (HighlightingChanged != null)
        {
            HighlightingChanged(type);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to write unit test cases for `ClearIPHighlighting`. How do i proceed.

```
  [Test(Description = "to ")] 
  public void ClearIPHighlightingTets()
  {
       UniformGridHighlighting.ClearIPHighlighting();
       //How to call method
  }
```

Comment: So, what is it you want to test?

Comment: want to test clearIPhighlighting method

Comment: In the current setup you can't, the code you shared only updates private stuff. What's the effect of clearing it? Can you see the result of the clear somewhere else?

Comment: You could test if the Event triggers as expected though.

Answer (score 0):

Given the current setup you can only test that the event is triggered.

```
 [Test()] 
 public void ThatTheEventIsTriggeredWhenTheListIsCleared()
 {
    // Arrange
    bool eventTriggered = false;
    UniformGridHighlighting.HighlightingChanged += _ => { eventTriggered= true; };

    //Act
    UniformGridHighlighting.ClearIPHighlighting();

    //Assert:
    Assert.IsTrue(eventTriggered);
 }
```

And that it's of the right type

```
 [Test(Description = "to ")] 
 public void ThatTheEventIsTriggeredWithTheIPArgumentWhenTheIPListIsCleared()
 {
    // Arrange
    HighlightType? type = null;
    UniformGridHighlighting.HighlightingChanged += x => { type = x; };

    //Act
    UniformGridHighlighting.ClearIPHighlighting();

    //Assert:
    Assert.AreEqual(s, HighlightType.IP);
 }
```

To test that your previous highlight was removed is going to be harder:

```
 [Test] 
 public void ThatTheIpIsNotHighlightedIfTheListWasCleared()
 {
    UniformGridHighlighting.HighlightIP("1.1.1.1");

    //Act
    UniformGridHighlighting.ClearIPHighlighting();
    UniformGridHighlighting.Highlihst(Grid);

    //Assert:
    //Go through the grid to figure out that the IP was not highlighted. The below is a total guess:
    bool wasHighlighted = Grid.Rows.Any(row => row.Cells.Any(Cell.Highlighted));
    Assert.Isfalse(wasHighlighted);
 }
```

Comment: In the end it is important to test the expected functionality, not whether it was implemented in a specific way. It might be that there is a different way to cleat the IP's, other than calling `_highlightedIPs.Clear();`, but if the result is the same, the test should not fail.